# Predicting average detention using Bayesian Statistics

Tags: r, probability, self-study, bayesian

I am complete beginner in Statistics and I've been having trouble with Bayesian inference. It will be great if anyone can help me with this question (it's a question from final preparation but due to covid, the professor is impossible to reach).

Schools in State A have been struggling with the number of detentions being given out. To properly assess how many detentions are being given out, the board issued a statistician to look into the numbers. It is formerly believed that the schools in average gave out 128 detentions with variance of 16. 50 schools were selected in random from 3 major cities to check this assumption. The results are as follows:

- City A: 152 detentions in average with standard deviation of 10
- City B: 137 detentions in average with standard deviation of 7
- City C: 171 detentions in average with standard deviation of 14

Use bayesian inference to

1. Calculate the new expected average of detention being given out in State A
2. What is the probability of schools having a detention average of greater than 160?

We also use R, so if using R is easier to explain (or calculate) then please do so.

Comment: Is this a homework? Please add a `[self-study]` tag and tell us more on how did you try solving it and where are you stuck?

Comment: no, this isn't a homework, its exam prep questions (from an old quiz I think). I don't really know where to begin. What we have been taught is work with the probability, not the actual number. For example, there is a box holding x number of balls. We believe that there is 1/5 chance of drawing the red ball. in experiment 1, we drew 6 balls and got 3 red balls. In experiment 2, we drew 13 balls and got 3 red balls......and so on. In this case, I know how to calculate the estimated probability of getting a red ball out of the box.

Comment: Is there a specified distribution for the prior beliefs? (ie Normal, Gamma, ...)

Comment: none were mentioned for this one, but before this, we used either binomial or beta distribution (primarily beta).

Comment: This sounds like a textbook example of all normal priors and textbook formulas to update the posterior using the sample averages and standard deviations along with the prior beliefs.